# Visual Studio project is placing object files in unrelated project directory. help

Tags: visual-studio, build

I have a visual studio solution that contains a project that builds a joystick handling library. Unfortunately, the output .lib file is placed in an unrelated folder on the drive. It is placed in another project. I noticed that $(TargetDir) is expanding to the unrelated project's path and not the current solutions path. How do I change this? I searched the visual studio project files for any matching path text and nothing turns up so I can't see how it is pointing to the wrong directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I screwed up. The project was pointing to the wrong directory (obviously) :-)